# Is there a way to see the type of inputs and outputs from the Rhino plugin Grasshopper 3D?

Tags: c#, java, grasshopper

An example of what I am attempting to do is below. Since Java is a static typed language, knowing the `type` of inputs and outputs is crucial. However, an application I was given to rewrite was written in a graphical programming language called Grasshopper 3D, which is a plugin to Rhino, an architecture software. Since I will be rewriting the components, I am interested in knowing the `type` of inputs and outputs. The input is usually easily to define, as the C# scripting component allows you to set input `type`, however, the output is usually unknown. Is there a SDK or source code online that will reveal Grasshopper 3D's input and output `type`s?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have proceeded to create more methods for similar functions while awaiting for an answer: http://puu.sh/5gs6f/bb35dcb364.png

Comment: Do you want to know the type before you 'return' it, or afterwards? The component will report the type once the script has run. P.s. what's Java got to do with it? Did you mean C#?